# Should I set up a password for mariadb.sys@localhost?

Tags: mariadb

I'm not clear what this user is for, but mysqltuner suggests I create a password for it.  I'm unclear if that's actually good practice, or if this is a limitation of mysqltuner simply because it's seen a user that it's not familiar with, that no exception has been coded for?

Running MariaDB 10.5.8

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a great [article](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/what-is-the-purpose-of-mysql-syslocalhost-user/) that explains the purpose of that account.

This section of the article in particular explains why MySQLTuner is complaining:

> It uses an invalid password (see the output of SHOW CREATE USER
> above). This ensures that should the account get unlocked by mistake,
> it is still impossible to login. It is thus recommended not to reset
> the password.

Comment: I had found that as well - so mysqltuner just has a bug and I should ignore it then.

Comment: Yea, I guess you can technically call it a big though it's moreso a weird design mechanism on MariaDB's part, in my opinion. But yes you can ignore it.